# How to make NTFS partition for storage alongside Ubuntu installation?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, 20.04

I have an extra external hard disk that I want to use as both:

1. an Ubuntu 20.04 linux boot drive and;
2. additional storage for my Windows machine.

I want so that

1. if I connect this HDD before boot, it boots Ubuntu.
2. If I connect HDD after boot, Windows mounts the NTFS partition.

But how do I partition this do I place

1. the NTFS partition in (far left) front, and then swap, and then ext4(/), and then FAT32 (/home) or;
2. NTFS partition at the end (far right) of Ubuntu partitions?

Comment: Is the HD external ?

Comment: Yes I will add it to my question

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? (In other words, is Windows installed in UEFI mode or BIOS mode?) If the computer was delivered with Windows 10, we can guess that it is booting in UEFI mode, but you can check it from an Ubuntu live drive according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/uefi).

Comment: in my opinion you can install ubuntu on the external hard disk(with 4 partitions /boot, swap, /root /home), and leave free space for example 100 gb and after that boot into windows and create a new NTFS Partition for storage

Comment: @sudodus I uh not sure. But I have changed my BIOS setting to boot from Legacy support and disabled secure boot I guess it's not UEFI anymore? Also my question above refer to installing Ubuntu on external drive separate from my internal Windows drive; not installing Ubuntu alongside Windows,. So external drive contains: (1.) Linux. (2.) empty NTFS and Intenal drive contains: (1.) Windows. Out of curiosity what does my internal hard drive UEFI/BIOS mode have anything to do with my external hard drive Linux partition though?

Comment: @kannzzmm2 Ah I see so you are suggesting that I leave free space unpartitioned and then from Windows Open Disk Management, Select the disk from which you want to make a partition, Right click the Un-partitioned space in the bottom pane and select New Simple Volume?

Comment: Booting from legacy mode is the same as booting in BIOS mode :-) This makes it easier to get a clean installation in the external drive. But it is important that (at the partitioning window of the installer) you select to install the grub bootloader into the external drive (the head of the drive, `/dev/sdx` where `x` may be `b` or `c` ... Then when booting, you should be able to press a hotkey (different between computers) to get a 'temporary boot menu', where you can select which drive to boot. Otherwise the computer will continue to boot into the internal drive.

Comment: You can create an NTFS partition (a partition with the NTFS file system) in the external drive using gparted in Ubuntu live. But yes, you can also let Windows format the drive. However, watch out, sometimes Windows wants to create a *dynamic* partition, and such a partition cannot be used by Ubuntu.

Comment: So where should I put the NTFS partition in gparted? Before swap (far left)? Before Ext4? After ext4?  or after the fat32 home (far right)?

Comment: With Windows 10 you can put the NTFS partition 'anywhere'. I would put it at the end (behind the operating system). -- Older Windows operating systems could only read partition number one in USB drives, but current Windows 10 can read all partitions, if there are Microsoft file systems (FAT32, exFAT, NTFS) or UDF. So if you intend to connect the external drive to a computer with Windows 8 or an older version, partition #1 should contain the NTFS file system.

Comment: @sudodus Your comments seem to be the answer! :)

Comment: @user68186, Maybe, let us follow the progress of the OP's task ...

Comment: @sudodus I have tried all the above but encounter a problem which is unrelated to ntfs or paritition and managed to fixed it here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252071/bios-grub-is-unable-to-detect-external-hard-disk-drive/1252072#1252072 In the end I made a uefi Ubuntu and leave free space at the end and because my /home is set to logical it's inside extended partition and from that extended partition I added NTFS partition. So please write an answer for future reader

Comment: @kannzzmm2 You should write an answer too for future reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... But how do I partition this do I place
>
> 1. the NTFS partition in (far left) front, and then swap, and then ext4(/), and then FAT32 (/home) or;
> 2. NTFS partition at the end (far right) of Ubuntu partitions?

- First we concluded that the internal drive with Windows boots in BIOS alias legacy mode, but you decided to boot this external drive in UEFI mode anyway.
- With Windows 10 you can put the NTFS partition 'anywhere'. I would put it at the end (behind the operating system).

  - Older Windows operating systems could only read partition number one in USB drives, but current Windows 10 can read all partitions, if there are Microsoft file systems (FAT32, exFAT, NTFS) or UDF. So if you intend to connect the external drive to a computer with Windows 8 or an older version, partition #1 should contain the NTFS file system.