# GRUB doesn't detect my other hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2

My device has an SSD ( with Linux and Windows on it) and and HDD for data with some ISO images on it.

Whenever I run `ls` on grub command line, I only get the first disk with its partitions only and the other disk is not detected by grub and I can't boot my disk images from there. This is most probably because I have fast boot enabled in my BIOS settings (I'm booting legacy if that matters). When it's disabled or I manually boot the SSD, grub detects the HDD normally.

So my question is, how do I get grub the see my other disk without disabling fast boot in bios? ( It once mattered alot before I updated my bios), is there a grub module I need to load first or something to get grub to see the HDD like an OS does ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You also need to explain what you are doing and why? Grub is a boot loader. Grub is not an OS as your last statement seems to say.

Comment: If disabling fast boot only mattered before your bios/uefi upgrade, why not disable it now?

Comment: If you updated UEFI, it often reverts multiple settings. Review all the UEFI settings you changed to install. Or a Windows update may have turned Windows fast start up back on. Grub/Ubuntu cannot see hibernated  partitions and fast start up sets hibernation flag.

Comment: @oldfred No I didn't update my bios recently and I'm refering to the fast boot **bios** option not that of windows ( I have it disabled so that kubuntu could access the shared ntfs partition rw). As @ HomerSimpson suggested, I think I should go with disabling the fast boot, I was looking for a workaround or a grub module to keep it on.

Comment: @David Kubuntu 21.10. I'm trying to boot some iso images from the HDD which doesn't get detected due to the fast boot bios setting. I'm looking for a workaround ( a grub module maybe) to get grub  to see and boot from it. and what I mean is that I'm looking for a way to initialize/discover that disk like an OS discovers it, but in the bootloader environment.

Comment: Have not seen any work around to use Windows fast start up & Linux. Grub cannot see hibernated partitions. That is to prevent use from Linux and then data loss. Fast boot is an UEFI setting, fast start up is  a Windows setting. You can turn fast boot back on in UEFI, if you know how to get back into UEFI as often there is not time to press the normal keys to get into UEFI settings or UEFI boot menu on a reboot. A full power down often then works for one normal boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you want to run is `ls -l`. It will show all devices and partitions with their UUID-s. For the complete manual see https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html.

Edit: The answer OP was searching for was found here:[BIOS/GRUB is unable to detect external hard disk drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252071/bios-grub-is-unable-to-detect-external-hard-disk-drive)

Comment: Still the same, doesn't display the second disk or its partitions.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This might be interesting for you though. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252071/bios-grub-is-unable-to-detect-external-hard-disk-drive

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. A module to see other disks. @HomerSimpson

Comment: I edited my answer with the link you were looking for. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing grub to the 2nd disk.

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory <some-path-on-target-disk-fs> /dev/sdb
```

Also I might consider Ventoy's non-destructive install, but I don't want to take the risk.

So I can keep fast boot and only boot from `sdb` when necessary